# Is there a way to simplify this css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Is there a way to simplify the following? If so how can I do it?

```
.ui-layout-north {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
.ui-layout-west {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
#inner {
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
#inner-center {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
#inner-south {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/xUvJk/2/

Comment: Also as a suggestion use classes, even for the #inner and #inner-center, they allow for reuse and and ID is 255 times more specific than a class making it harder to overwrite those rules else where. Use a class of .inner and if you need to have an ID on that element do so, but don't use it for styling rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate each identifier with a comma to apply the same style to multiple elements:

```
#inner, #inner-center, #inner-south ... {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

and then just specify for each element that has different style:

```
#inner { 
    border-left : inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Factorize then specify. Using only the classes:

```
.ui-layout-center, .ui-layout-south, .ui-layout-north, .ui-layout-west {
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ui-layout-north {
    border-bottom-style:solid;
}

.ui-layout-west {
    border-right-style: solid;
}

.ui-layout-center {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.ui-layout-south {
    border-top-style: solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hQ5mY/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-layout-north,
.ui-layout-west,
#inner,
#inner-center,
#inner-south {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0px;    
}

.ui-layout-north {
    /* specify unique styles */
}

.ui-layout-west {
    /* specify unique styles */
}

#inner {
    /* specify unique styles */
}

#inner-center {
    /* specify unique styles */
}

#inner-south {
    /* specify unique styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-layout-north, .ui-layout-west, #inner, #inner-center {
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ui-layout-north, .ui-layout-west , #inner-center, #inner-south{
   border-left: none;
   padding: 0px;
}

.ui-layout-west, #inner, #inner-south {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.ui-layout-north, #inner, #inner-south {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Each block has a different set of specifiers.

Comment: Sorry. I should have put on my reading glasses first. I now see the others have already presented viable answers.